# How to download file from remote server with asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webclient

I have a asp.net core 3 application.

And I try to download a log file from a server with address: 123.456.789.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to notice:

- The address 123.456.789. doesn't look that valid to me, hope is just a random address you posted
- The exception is on the HttpContext of the request you are performing to your app, not the request you make to 123.456.789. Basically is failing here "_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("App_Data")"

So, make sure you get the correct path where to store the file

I recommend you to first create an small console app to download the file locally (save it to C:\Temp\file.txt), once you have that working integrate that with the webapi, find the right way to retrieve AppData folder (which should not be in session)

Comment: Read the exceptio, it says it can't find the destination directory DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC15\u_ex200621.txt'.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it is the correct address. This is the address on the server: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC15 and in that folder there is a file with name: u_ex200621.txt

Comment: you need to make sure the app has permissions to write in that folder, try first in another directory where you know the app can write

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is:

- use `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`. `HttpClient` is supperior in every
  way.
- write response stream from `HttpClient` response to `FileStream`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogs(string id)
{
    // Set reasonable IP so HttpClient won't fail
    string remoteFileUrl = "http://myuri.com/file.txt";
    // Not sure what's happening here. Make sure it's pointing to reasonable
    // location on machine.
    // string localFileName = Path.Combine(_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("App_Data"), "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\W3SVC15\\u_ex200621");
    string localFileName = "C:\\downloads\\some_file.txt"

    // Injecting via ASP.NET depenency injection is recommended however
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
    var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(remoteFileUrl);

    using (var fs = File.Create(localFileName)) 
    {
        httpResponse.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: it should be something like `https://stackoverflow.com/`. Basically HTTP valid URI

Comment: @NiceTobeBottleInfinity seems to be an issue with SSL certificate. Need to debug this on case by case basis.

Comment: So this is locaion on my server: C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC19

Comment: Are you sure that file on remote server is exposed by http?